# map through array nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have a stripe function where I am trying to push the images into the array for each product. This is part of the prebuilt stripe checkout page...  here's my function at whole:

```
//defining arrays
var productsArray = [];
var priceArray = [];
var imageArray = [];
//query to database

var productsStripe = "select * from " + tableID + "";
ibmdb.open(db2ConnString, function(err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  conn.query(productsStripe,  async function (err, rows) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log(rows)

    var itemName = ""
    var itemPrice = ""
    var totalNewPriceTest = ""

    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)     
    //inserting items and prices into arrays
     productsArray.push(rows[i]['NAME'])
     priceArray.push(rows[i]['PRICE'])
     imageArray.push(rows[i]['IMAGE_URL'])

    }
   
  
    //stripe
            // loop over products array to construct the line_items
        const items = productsArray.map((product, i) => {
            return {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'CAD',
                product_data: {
                name: product,
                images: imageArray[i]
                },
                unit_amount: parseInt(priceArray[i], 10) * 100,
            },
            quantity: 1,
            };
        });
```

its returning the error: `(node:39728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid array`

how do I get the image array to populate the stripe page with images too? I pushed the values into the array, and am calling them , but not sure why it is returning invalid array. any ideas?

Comment: The code is too long yo be read by the community. Please reduce it to minimal reproducible example and point the line where error is thrown.

Comment: @ShivamSingla just made it shorter :)

Comment: Error at which line?

Comment: Async and await should be used together to resolve a promise

Comment: @ShivamSingla `images: imageArray[I],` this line, which in the code is above is under the productsArray.map() function

Comment: @Masood how would this help?

Comment: Could you please log`imageArray` just before `map`  method?

Comment: Let me fix your code

Comment: Inferring from prop name `images` in the object, it seems it needs to be an array. But if `imageArray` id a 1D array, then `imageArray[i]` is not an array. Is it ok?

Comment: @Masood, misuse of `async` is not the cause of problem at hand. Please don't extend comments with side-comments.

Comment: @ShivamSingla when I changed `images: imageArray[I],` to `images: imageArray`, it actually worked, but the problem is, all the product images are the same one, although it should be 4 different products there

Comment: Try `images: [imageArray[i]]`?

Comment: @Masood, if a function is marked as *async*, it need not to be async actually. It may have no `await` statement in its body. But vice-versa is not true. If a function has `await` in its body, it must be marked as `asyn`.

Comment: @Gianluca shall I write explanation in the answer or you got it?

Comment: @ShivamSingla Doesn't the DB query return a promise? If yes, then it must be resolved.

Comment: @Masood I don't know what DB is used here. I am telling concepts of JS which are irrelevant of any library used.

Comment: @Masood, moreover, I guess, you have used "promise must be resolved" incorrectly. Promise can be either resolved or reject. It may be left unhandled in any case.

Comment: @Masood, yes, but it was because of invalid array :), which is now RESOLVED.

Comment: @ShivamSingla actually could you explain just so I know for next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observations

- `imageArray` is array containing image urls for different products, one for each product in the `productArray`.
- From the name of the prop `images`, the error message and the error line info provided by the OP, the prop `images` ought to be an array.

In the code, `image: imageArray[i]` means that the `image` prop is assigned a string but it should be array. So changing it with `[imageArray[i]]`, we are assigning an array of length one to `image` prop containing image url for that product.